# Cytoscape cannot read property 'className' of null

Tags: angular, typescript, cytoscape.js

I am trying to integrate cytoscape in angular application.

First of all I downloaded:

```
npm i --save ngx-cytoscape cytoscape @types/cytoscape
```

then I imported Cytoscape library into module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ItemComponent } from './item/item.component';

import { CytoscapeModule } from 'ngx-cytoscape';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    CytoscapeModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    ItemComponent
  ]
})
export class DashboardModule { }
```

and updated Angular.json

```
"scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
              "node_modules/cytoscape/dist/cytoscape.js"
            ]
```

From now I can use cytoscape
This is my html

```
<div id="cy" class='row justify-content-center cytograph mt-2' *ngIf="graphData">
  <ngx-cytoscape [elements]="graphData"></ngx-cytoscape>
</div>
```

This is my typescript file

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-item',
    templateUrl: './item.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./item.component.css']
})
export class ItemComponent {
    traces: Trace[];

    private _graphData: any;

    constructor(
        private traceService: TraceService
    ) { }

    // event that triggers when button is clicked
    showDetails(correlationId: string): void {
        this.traceService.findByCorrelationId(correlationId)
            .subscribe(
                (traces) => {
                    this.traces = traces;
                },
                (error) => {
                    // error handling
                },
                () => {
                    this.createGraphData();
                }
            );
    }

    createGraphData(): void {
        const nodes: Node[] = [];
        const edges: Edge[] = [];
        // some logic...
        this._graphData = cytoscape ({ container: document.getElementById('cy'), elements: {nodes, edges }});
    }

    get graphData(): any {
        return this._graphData;
    }

    set graphData(value: any) {
        this._graphData = value;
    }
}
```

The problem is this line of code

```
this._graphData = cytoscape ({ container: document.getElementById('cy'), elements: {nodes, edges }});
```

When I create _graphData [accoring to ngx-cytoscape documentation](https://github.com/calvinvette/ngx-cytoscape/blob/master/cytodemo/cytodemo.component.ts) like this:

```
this._graphData = { nodes, edges };
```

everything works perfectly the problem is I don't know how to apply 'styles' ngx demo works however they are not showing how to access style [].

When I try to follow this demo http://embed.plnkr.co/O7mWEfZuIhhtahdAhsAM/ and wrap _graphData into cytoscape object in order to have acces to "style []" I get following error:

> TypeError: cannot read property 'className' of null

Any idea what I am doing wrong or how to apply styles in cytoscape in angular application ?
Thanks

Answer (score 7):

I know, this is a late answer, but will help somebody. I experienced the same error and did the following

You are referring to `document.getElementById('cy')`. you could have forgotten to add the **cy** element in html  or check the spelling

Comment: See my question there's html snippet with including div id="cy"

Comment: in fact this did help! I had the div below the script, so that's why it wasn't defined **yet**